# Two different relations between same two models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, models, rails-models

I have two models: `users` and `emails`.

[image]

I have separated this tables because we want the user to be able to have many emails in the same user account, and also easily check uniqueness of email values among accounts.

`primary_email_id` is a FK of a unique `email`, but also a `user` has many `emails`. How do I say that in the rails model?

I was trying

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # relations
  has_many :emails
  has_one :primary_email
end
…
class Email < ActiveRecord::Base
  # relations
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Is that correct? How does rails know when I say `primary_email` I'm making reference to the `emails` table?

By the way, both migrations are:

```
create_table :users do |t|
  t.string :username
  t.string :first_name
  t.string :last_name
  t.binary :password
  # t.integer :primary_email

  t.timestamps null: false
end

create_table :emails do |t|
  # t.integer :user
  t.string :email
  t.boolean :verified

  t.timestamps null: false
end

add_reference :users, :primary_email, references: :emails, index: true, foreign_key: true
add_reference :emails, :user, index: true, foreign_key: true
```

Comment: why don't you insert another boolean column in `Email` table named `primary_email`? Set it to `true` if the `email` is unique.

Comment: @Emu I thought of it, but after doing that, how would I be able to get that email using something like `user.primary_email` instead of iterating over `user.emails` to find which is the primary one?

Comment: `@primary_email = Email.where("user_id = ? and primary = ?", @user.id, 1)` Point is, don't make things harder than they need to be.

Comment: @MarsAtomic and each time `primary_email` is accesed, a query is going to be executed?

Comment: create a `scope` in your `Email`, `scope :primary_emails, -> { where('primary_email = ?', true) }`. Then `@user.emails.primary_emails`.

Comment: user.primary_email would also be running a query. How do you think Rails gets that information without a query? You can cut down your query by joining users and emails and using an includes clause, however.