# Undefined method in User model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am a beginner in rails, and I'm having an issue in a registration form.

I have `users` and `emails` in different tables ([take a look](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31889580/two-different-relations-between-same-two-models)) but the user registration form has an `email` field mixed with all the other fields such as username and password.

At first render there's no issue, but when trying to save, if any error occurs (such as duplicated `username` or `email`) I follow steps [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html), where it says (don't `redirect_to`, just do `render 'new'` to keep previously inserted info. That's when it throws an error saying `email` is not known.

I don't want to create the field `email` in the `users` table, since I already removed it from the original model. How do I fix that?

## Form code

```
<%= form_for :user, url: users_path do |f| %>
<p>
  <%= f.label :username %>
  <%= f.text_field :username %>
</p>
<p>
  <%= f.label :name %>
  <%= f.text_field :name %>
</p>
<p>
  <%= f.label :email %>
  <%= f.email_field :email # Error is thrown in this line %>
</p>
<p>
  <%= f.label :password %>
  <%= f.password_field :password %>
</p>
<p>
  <%= f.label :password_confirmation %>
  <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %>
</p>
<p>
  <%= f.submit %>
</p>
```

## Controller code

```
def create
  # render plain: params[:user].inspect
  @user = User.new(user_registration_params)
  if @user.save
    email_params = {email: params[:user][:email], primary: true}
    @email = Email.new(email_params)
    @email.user = @user
    if @email.save
      redirect_to @user
    else
      @user.destroy
    end
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have connected the both models via belongs_to you can set up your form to update/create both models.

You have to declare you user with `accepts_nested_attributes_for`.

See a full example here:

http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1

Comment: @unmultimedio this second issue seems unrelated to the first. Please consider accepting this answer, as it seems to have solved your issue, and creating a second question for your new issue.